# Type error, unit256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct

Tags: solidity, struct, error, returndata

Using sol compiler 0.5.1

I am trying to fetch data from old smart contract's function called people, the smart contract is already deployed on the blockchain

```
mapping(address => Person ) public people;
```

and in new contract i imported it and define like this

```
ADNIOX token;
      
constructor () public {
                        token = ADNIOX(0x5244e79314c710E5cA2715c071F3d2750CcAEa90);
                            }
```

Below is the response I get.

```
token.people(_addr);
```

now i want do check some variable values from above response and process according to it.

```
Person memory p = token.people(_addr);

(uint a,address b,uint256 c,uint256 d,ADNIOX.userState e ,ADNIOX.withdrawState f ,ADNIOX.remainToken g ,uint256 h,uint256 i) = token.people(_addr);
```

I tried both ways but it haven't worked for me.

The contract is deployed here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6dc4e20f7fd3540793d9dcb337667f5c5b8f0cb2#readContract

The contract gives the values of whole object

[image: Response]

The problem for me is that I want to check the value of one of these variables and compare it to my defined criteria and then proceed to complete the code.

Comment: What is `Person`?

Comment: Please share the code of both files.

Comment: Person is a struct containing user details

Comment: You can find the source code for the contract on which I am working here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6dc4e20f7fd3540793d9dcb337667f5c5b8f0cb2